# How to put menu in actionbar with actionbarsherlock and slidemenu?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

So I've been trying to get a menu in the actionbar with actionbarsherlock and slidemenu.

But the menu appears at the bottom instead of within the actionbar. What am I doing wrong?

Here is a screenshot how it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcIDg.jpg
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbNg6.png)

I've overriden the onOptionsItemSelected and the onCreateOptionsMenu method. But it the menu just doesn't show up on top. :(

```
public class MainActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    arcList = new MenuFragment(this);

    for (Registry item : Registry.values())
        arcList.addItem(item.name(), item.iconR);

    // set the Above View
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, Registry.Build.getFragmentList())
            .commit();

    // configure the SlidingMenu
    menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
    menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
    menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
    menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
    menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW);
    menu.setMenu(R.layout.menu_frame);

    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.menu_frame, arcList)
            .commit();

    arcList.lastItemList = Registry.Build;

    setSlidingActionBarEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    View customNav = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.navigation, null);
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(customNav);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);

    menu.showMenu();
    setTitle("Build");
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(Registry.Build.iconR_i);

    setContentView(R.layout.content_frame);
    setBehindContentView(R.layout.content_frame);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            toggle();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Here is the menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu" android:icon="@drawable/randomicon"
      android:title="@string/menutitle!" android:titleCondensed="@string/randomtitle" android:visible="true"/>
    </menu>
```

Any help or hint is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Funny after 5 hours trying out examples, the moment I gave up and asked here I found the solution ~.~

Turns out android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" was set in the androidmanifest all along without me noticing.